# Получение всех возможных комбинаций значений атрибута таблицы БД

Tags: sql, ms-access

Имеется база из таблиц: студенты, группы и ведомости. В последней указаны оценки за экзамены. Нужно каким-то образом вывести все возможные пары студентов, в которых у первого средний балл выше, чем у второго, и отсортировать это всё по группам. Мне кажется тут требуется сформировать большую таблицу со всеми возможными комбинациями студентов и их баллами, а затем просто сделать из неё выборку по признаку avg(1)>avg(2). Но можно ли перебрать все комбинации студентов, и если да, то как? Заранее спасибо..

upd1. В таблице студентов просто ряд фамилий: Петров, Гуськов, Иванов и названия групп, в которых они учатся.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблице ведомостей указаны оценки за предметы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечная цель - получение таблицы из 4-х столбцов: Фамилия 1 студента, его средний балл, фамилия 2го студента, и его средний балл, при этом средний балл первого должен быть больше среднего балла второго

Comment: Дополните вопрос меткой вашей СУБД, примером данных, результатом и тем, как вы хотите решать. А то сложно понять, что вы спрашиваете

Comment: как как, заджойнить таблицу саму на себя, исключив совпадение id студентов, и добавив упомянутый avg и группу

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, INNER JOIN тут не подойдёт, так как с его помощью мы можем лишь создать пары одинаковых фамилий... Тогда FULL JOIN? Уж простите за глупые вопросы...

Comment: INNER вполне подойдет. объединение задается исключительно условиями. сделайте условие, что `A.id!=B.id` вот и получите все пары кроме соединения самого с собой

Comment: то что останется после inner join будет зависеть от того, какие условия склейки таблиц  вы напишите. так что если вы укажите совпаденеи id студентов обоих таблиц, то и получите пары одинаковых.

Comment: Все, понял в чем моя ошибка. Просто раньше я всегда склеивал таблицы по общему столбцу, и получал просто выборку из нескольких таблиц. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге обошелся вообще без использования join:

```
SELECT 
с1.Фамилия AS first_stud, с2.Фамилия AS second_stud, с1.student_avg AS 
avg_first, с2.student_avg AS avg_second, с1.Код_группы AS код_гр_1, 
с2.Код_группы AS код_гр_2
FROM 
(SELECT Студент.Фамилия, Avg(Ведомость.Оценка) AS student_avg, 
Студент.Код_группы
FROM Студент INNER JOIN Ведомость ON 
Студент.Номер_студбилета=Ведомость.Номер_студбилета
GROUP BY Код_группы, Студент.Фамилия) AS с1, 
(SELECT Студент.Фамилия, Avg(Ведомость.Оценка) AS student_avg, 
Студент.Код_группы
FROM Студент INNER JOIN Ведомость ON 
Студент.Номер_студбилета=Ведомость.Номер_студбилета
GROUP BY Код_группы, Студент.Фамилия) AS с2
WHERE 
с1.student_avg>с2.student_avg AND
с1.Код_группы=с2.Код_группы;
```